# Eclipse + Tomcat 8 - application double deployment

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I'm developing for Tomcat 8 under Eclipse Mars. 
This is my application context in published server.xml:

```
<Context docBase="C:\automation\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\webapps\ROOT" path="" reloadable="false"/>
<Context docBase="AutomationWeb" path="/automation" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:AutomationWeb"/>
```

No other contexts defined there. But when I open tomcat manager app I see 2 contexts for my application:

One with "/AutomationWeb" path,
other with "/automation" path

My app has no context.xml

What I've discovered:

1. They share display name from my application's web.xml
2. My application can run on both paths.
3. The one with /AutomationWeb path is not actually reloadable
4. If I remove my application(Web Module) from Tomcat server in Eclipse, both entries disappear from tomcat manager app.
5. Deleting server in Eclipse and deleting contents of \workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\ didn't help.

How can I remove undesired application context with /AutomationWeb path? What configs should i check?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by changing publish directory from webapps to webappsauto. It seems the problem was in server.xml because of this statement:

```
<Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
```